# Cannot get a meaningful response to the command 'gem list '

Tags: ruby, gems

I know I have gems installed because the response to the command

```
$ gem environment 
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
```

OK, now I want to know which gems are installed, so I type:

```
$ gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
```

What does this mean, or hint at , 
and why doesn't the command return my list of gems?

Comment: How does having `gem environment` showing the version tell you you have gems installed?

Comment: I guess it only means I have the gems _environment_ installed, ready to accept installation of specific gems, none of which had been installed yet.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, the header:

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

always displays. If you have no gems installed, that is all that displays.
If you have any gems installed, they will be listed below this header.
(Discovered this by trying the same command on a different system - 
evidently I had no gems installed in the Ubuntu system - thought I did).